# How to subset a sapply function output

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, vectorization

Given a dataframe, I would like to use `strsplit` on one of my columns, and return the first element of the vector. Here is the example:

```
testdf<- data.frame(col1= c('string1.string2', 'string3.string4'),
                    col2= c('somevalue', 'someothervalue'),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to generate a new column such as
`testdf$col3 <- c('string1', 'string3')`

I tried the following:

```
testdf$col3<- strsplit(testdf$col1, split = '\\.')[[1]])[1]
```

which, of course, doesn't work. It returns just the first element of the output ('string1') and writes it for the whole column.
One solution would be to write a custom function:

```
customfx<- function(ind_cell){
 my_out<- strsplit(ind_cell, split = '\\.')[[1]][1]
 return(my_out)}
```

Then use it with `sapply`. I was wondering if there is an alternative  to this. The talking stick is yours :)

Comment: Edited the example to clarify the desired output

Comment: Use `testdf$col3 <- sapply(strsplit(testdf$col1, split = '\\.'), \`[\`, 1)`

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::separate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` (which is vectorized) with *regex* for this:

```
testdf$col3 <- sub("^([^.]+).*", "\\1", testdf$col1)

testdf
#             col1           col2    col3
#1 string1.string2      somevalue string1
#2 string3.string4 someothervalue string3
```

Here use `^([^.]+).*` to match the whole string and capture the substring from the beginning until a dot is met, then replace the whole string with the captured group using back reference.

Comment: I appreciate you adding the explanation, that's something I often need :)